# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 
$A= \left( 
      \begin{matrix}
        3  & 1 \\
       -3 & 7 \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right)
$

So:

$$\det (A-\lambda I_2)= \left| 
      \begin{matrix}
        3-\lambda  & 1 \\
       -3 & 7-\lambda \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right|
  =\lambda^2-10\lambda+24
$$
$$\lambda^2-10\lambda+24=(\lambda-6)\cdot(\lambda-4) \implies \text{eigenvalues =}\{6,4\}$$

Replacing in the eigenbasis formula:
$$E(\lambda)=\{x\in\Bbb R^n: \text{Ax} = \lambda\text{x}\}=\text{N}(\text{A} -\lambda I_n)$$

Then

$E(4)=N\left( 
      \begin{matrix}
        -1  & 1 \\
       -3 & 3 \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right)
$

$
E(6)= N\left( 
      \begin{matrix}
        -3  & 1 \\
       -3 & 1 \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right)
$

This is easy, but my professor wrote this:

We see that $v_1= \left[ 
      \begin{matrix}
        1  \\
        1 \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right]
$
give a basis for $E(4)$
and $v_2= \left[ 
      \begin{matrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right]
$ gives a basis for $E(6)$

The truth is that I can't see nothing, because I don't know about "basis". And I can't understand how to get $v_1$ and $v_2$

Someone can explain with some details about $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Comment: $E(\lambda)$ is the *null space* of $A-\lambda I_n$; it is not the matrix itself.

Comment: Sorry, edited!!!

Comment: That's ok! Now are you saying you don't know what a "basis" is, or that you aren't sure how to calculate the null space?

Answer (score 3):

If we add the component of each row of the matrix we find $4$ so we  see that $v_1= \left[ 
      \begin{matrix}
        1  \\
        1 \\
      \end{matrix}
    \right]
$
give a basis for $E(4)$ but this observation isn't a general method to find the eigenvector.

Comment: Have a great day my dear brother Sami. :+)

Comment: Nice work, Sami!